# On the modes of convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \sin \left(\frac{x}{k+1} \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Show that

> $$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k} \sin \left(\dfrac{x}{k+1}\right).$$

converges pointwise on $\mathbb{R}$ and uniformly on each bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$, to a differentiable function $f$ which satisifies $\vert f(x) \vert \leq \vert x \vert$ and $\vert f'(x) \vert \leq 1$.

This problem comes from a section that covers the Weierstrass M-Test and Dirichlet's Test. I am not sure where to begin with this. Analysis really isn't my thing at this point.

Comment: Are you trying to prove those statements about $f$, or something else?

Comment: Yes, sorry I left that off

Comment: Have you tried using those tests in any fashion?

Comment: Note that $|\sin t|\leq |t|$ for every real number $t$.

Comment: I am trying to use Dirichlet's now.

Comment: If I get $\frac{1}{k}$ converges to 0 uniformly and that the partial sums of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sin \frac{x}{k+1}$ are bounded then I can apply Dirichlet's, correct?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry you're just getting your answer in five years. Lets have a look at this;

Let $[a,b]\subseteq \Bbb{R}$ be any bounded interval, $x\in [a,b]$ and $k\in \Bbb{N},$ then

\begin{align} \left|\dfrac{1}{k}\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{k+1}\right)\right|\leq  \dfrac{1}{k}\left|\dfrac{x}{k+1}\right|=\dfrac{\left|x\right|}{k(k+1)} \leq \dfrac{\left|x\right|}{k(k+1)} \leq \dfrac{c}{k(k+1)} ,  \end{align}
where $c:=\max\{|a|,|b|\}\quad$   [see [If $x\in[a,b],$ then $|x|\leq \max\{|a|,|b|\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3055953/if-x-ina-b-then-x-leq-max-a-b]). Since 
\begin{align} \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{c}{k(k+1)} ,  \end{align}
converges, then,
 \begin{align} \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k}\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{k+1}\right)   \end{align}
converges uniformly on $[a,b],$ by Weierstrass-M test. Since $[a,b]\subseteq \Bbb{R}$ was arbitrary, then uniform convergence is true on each bounded interval in $\Bbb{R}$ which also implies pointwise convergence on $\Bbb{R}$. Now, for arbitrary $x\in\Bbb{R},$

\begin{align} \left|f(x)\right|&=\left|\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k}\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{k+1}\right)\right|\\&\leq \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \dfrac{1}{k}\left|\dfrac{x}{k+1}\right|\\&= \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{\left|x\right|}{k(k+1)}\\&= \left|x\right|\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k(k+1)}\\&= \left|x\right|\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum^{n}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k(k+1)} \\&= \left|x\right|\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum^{n}_{k=1}\left(\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{k+1}\right)\\&= \left|x\right|\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right) \\&= \left|x\right|.  \end{align}
Since the series converges uniformly on $[a,b],$ then we can differentiate term-term on $[a,b].$ Thus, for $x\in [a,b]$
\begin{align} f'(x)&=\dfrac{d}{dx}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k}\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{k+1}\right)\\&=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k}\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{k+1}\right)\right]\\&=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k}\left(\dfrac{1}{k+1}\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{x}{k+1}\right) ,  \end{align}
which implies that 
\begin{align} \left|f'(x)\right|&=\left|\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k}\left(\dfrac{1}{k+1}\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{x}{k+1}\right)\right|\\&\leq\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k}\left(\dfrac{1}{k+1}\right)\left|\cos\left(\dfrac{x}{k+1}\right) \right|\\&\leq\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k}\left(\dfrac{1}{k+1}\right)\\&= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum^{n}_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k(k+1)} \\&= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum^{n}_{k=1}\left(\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{k+1}\right)\\&= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right) \\&= 1   \end{align}
as required.