# If $x\in[a,b],$ then $|x|\leq \max\{|a|,|b|\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, absolute-value

The following seems to be quite known:

> If $x\in[a,b],$ then $|x|\leq \max\{|a|,|b|\}$

I do use it while treating problems on series of functions but how does it come about? Any hint please?

Comment: Sorry, can you tell me why you're voting for a close? Perhaps, I'll change somethings.

Comment: $|x|$ is the distance of $x$ from $0$, it seems obvious that the distance of $x$ from $0$ would be less than the maximum of distance of $a$ and $b$ from $0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $x\ge0$ then $b\ge0$,  hence $$|x|=x\le b=|b|\le\max(|a|,|b|).$$Similarly if $x<0$ then $a<0$, hence $$|x|=-x\le-a=|a|\le\max(|a|,|b|).$$

Comment: Can't it be $x\in [-5,4]$ for example, which means that $x$ can also be positive and negative as well ?

Comment: @Rebellos Huh???? Saying $x\in[-5,4]$ does not say that $x$ is both positive and negative - that's total nonsense.

Comment: Very straightforward proof +1

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You hadn't added the second line when I commented :) Still, it's a correct proof. +1 now.

Comment: @Rebellos Saying $x\in[-5,4]$ implies that $x$ is both positive  and negative is nonsense, regardless of  whhether I included that second line. No real number is both positive and negative.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I don't really see the nonsense. If $x \in [-5,4]$, this means that $x$ can take both positive **and** negative values.

Comment: @Rebellos $x$ is fixed

Answer (score 2):

Since $x \in [a,b]$, it is $a<b$ (or even $a \leq b$ if you want to be more strict for a trivial case).

If $\text{sgn}(a) = \text{sgn}(b)=1$, then $\max\{|a|,|b|\} = |b| \implies |x| \leq \max\{|a|,|b|\}$.

If $\text{sgn}(a) = \text{sgn}(b)=-1$, then $\max\{|a|,|b|\} = |a| \implies |x| \leq \max\{|a|,|b|\}$.

In the case of $\text{sgn}(a) \neq \text{sgn}(b)$, that means that $a$ would be negative. But, in that case, it can be $|a| > |b|$. Then, for $|x|$, it would be : $|x| \leq |a| \implies |x| \leq \max\{|a|,|b|\}$.

So, for all cases, we have that : $|x| \leq \max\{|a|,|b|\}$.

**Edit (Alternativelly) :** The comment of Jakobian is really nice to consider for a really straightforward proof. What the absolute value $|x|$ means is the distance of $x$ from $0$. But since $x \in [a,b]$, then this distance cannot be larger than the distance of $a$ from zero $(|a|)$ or the distance of $b$ from zero $(|b|)$.

Comment: I do not understand your first statement. If I have $a=-3$ and $b=-2$, then the maximum of $|a|$ and $|b|$ would be $|a|=3$, not $|b|=2$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Sure, edited. I missed a line.